# javascript function that works with multiple values

Tags: javascript

i have this HTML code inside a for in PHP

```
<div class="wrap-num-product">
    <div class="btn-num-product-down">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-minus"></i>
    </div>

    <input disabled class="num-product" type="number"  id="num-product"  value="'.$qty.'" max="'.$max_qty.'" min="1" />

    <div class="btn-num-product-up">
        <i class="fs-16 zmdi zmdi-plus"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my JS

```
$('.btn-num-product-down').on('click', function(){
        var min_value_product=Number(document.getElementById("num-product").min);
        var numProduct = Number($(this).next().val());
        if(numProduct > min_value_product) $(this).next().val(numProduct - 1);
    });

    $('.btn-num-product-up').on('click', function(){
        var max_value_product=Number(document.getElementById("num-product").max);;
        var numProduct = Number($(this).prev().val());
         if(numProduct < max_value_product) $(this).prev().val(numProduct + 1);
    });
```

this code shows

[image]

This code allows me to add 1 to the total value of num-product and stop it when it reaches the maximum value (max_qty), the problem is when in the cart i have more than one product, max_value_product takes only the max value from the first input num-product and i need the JS take the maximum value of each of the num-product inputs

Comment: consider a mv* pattern for this.

Comment: Element ID's must be unique by definition.